# How do I get this vine thing off me?

Tags: sonic-3-and-knuckles, sonic-and-knuckles

I'm attached to this vine and the if I try to run away it just pulls me back. I've tried jumping but it just pulls me back faster.

[image: Help! I'm stuck!]

The yellow things seem to appear as I run.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do a Spin Dash (hold down and press the jump button)!

Comment: I was going to answer this but I forgot if Knuckles can do that.

Comment: [There, I fixed it.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-a-barrel-roll)

Answer (score 1):

On Xbox, you hold <kbd>LS</kbd> Down and hold <kbd>A</kbd>, Release <kbd>LS</kbd> and you finally escape!

It works with Knuckles AND Sonic.

Comment: You can actually tap 'A' rapidly to speed up the spin dash :)